# VSCode column selection with keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

Any way to do this kind of selection using **only** the keyboard?

[image]

With the regular Visual Studio I would use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrows</kbd> to get these columns selected. Unfortunately it doesn't work in VSCode.

Answer (score 65):

By default, this is <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Arrow</kbd>.

If you would like to rebind it to align with Visual Studio, put this in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+down",
    "command": "cursorColumnSelectDown",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+left",
    "command": "cursorColumnSelectLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+pagedown",
    "command": "cursorColumnSelectPageDown",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+pageup",
    "command": "cursorColumnSelectPageUp",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+right",
    "command": "cursorColumnSelectRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "shift+alt+up",
    "command": "cursorColumnSelectUp",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

This will conflict with the default functions of that duplicating a line or growing/shrinking with smart select, so you can add this to swap those to require <kbd>Control</kbd>:

```
,
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+down",
    "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+up",
    "command": "editor.action.copyLinesUpAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+right",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.grow",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+left",
    "command": "editor.action.smartSelect.shrink",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: This has been one of my biggest pet peeves with VS Code since I started using it. This makes it so much more usable, you da best!

Comment: On MACOS : Command + Shift + Alt/Option + arrows.

Comment: Best usable answer, copy to keybindings.json and get back to work. Great job

Answer (score 11):

You can see your current keyboard shortcuts using the menu "File" -> "Preferences" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts". And then search by "cursorColum"[image]

Comment: On Mac OS 'Preferences' is located in the menu "Code" instead of "File".

Answer (score 7):

Here's what just worked for me with vscode:

```
Version: 1.39.2 (user setup)
Commit: 6ab598523be7a800d7f3eb4d92d7ab9a66069390
Date: 2019-10-15T15:35:18.241Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362
```

1. place cursor at upper left of block to select
2. hold down ctrl-alt-shift
3. press down-arrow however many times you want
4. press right-arrow however many times you want

When step 3 was to press right-arrow it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can do column selection several ways,

- As you've noted, Place cursor to the start (left) of first word of first column press and hold <kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd> followed by <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to select top row
  (Try <kbd>Ctrl + Shift</kbd> if previous key combination is not working). With the keys pressed proceed with selecting the column by pressing <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> key.
- Place cursor to the start (left) of first word of first column
  Press and hold <kbd>Alt + Shift</kbd> and repeatedly press <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> ***to add more cursors***.
  (Some versions of VSCode also use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift</kbd> instead)
  Once cursors added select the words by a simple <kbd>Shift + Right Arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> selects **next occurrence** of the word currently under cursor.
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd> selects **all occurrences** of word currently selected under cursor, regardless of if those words are above of below the cursor.

Comment: None of them worked here. I still couldn't do like on regular Visual Studio ALT + Arrows.

Comment: @AndréLuizCarletti you probably have an older version of VSCode.

Comment: I am using Version 1.11.2. Date 2017-04-13. Do I need any special plugin to get the shortcut working?

Answer (score 4):

Default keybinding in VSC...

<kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ARROW</kbd> (Mac)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ARROW</kbd> (PC?)

This answer is for those who appreciate default keyboard shortcuts. I prefer them because they work (out of the box) when I use other machines and when starting up on a new Mac.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to install [Visual Studio Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings):

1. Open *View -> Extensions* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>)
2. Search for *visual studio keymap*
3. Install it & restart VSCode

Now column selection available by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrows</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do the following:

1. Open Keybind settings: `ctrl+k,ctrl+s`.
2. Remove keybindings for `Notebook: Copy Cell <Up/Down>` and `Copy Line <Up/Down>`.
3. Search keybindings for `cursorColumnSelect <Up/Down>`.
4. Reassign the bindings that say `When: textInputFocus` to `Shift+Alt+<arrow keys>`.

Answer (score 0):

See [Column selection like Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669867/column-selection-like-visual-studio) and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#column-selection-mode

**Column selection mode** may be coming in v1.43 or soon, see demo in link above.  It will be an option in the `Selection` menu.

Works best with mouse but key shortcuts possible too:

> While this is checked, selecting with the mouse will create a column
>   selection and Shift+arrow keys and Shift+Page Up/Down keys will also
>   create column selection.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime text has this shortcut to select columns: Ctrl + Alt + Up or         Ctrl + Alt + Down.

So with adding this extension to VSCode: Sublime Text Keymap and Settings Importer.

You can just use the shortcut and done!.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an extension that lets you create cursors and selections, wherever you want in the document, with the keyboard. It works by simply placing inactive cursors and selections, and then activate them on demand.

And I think this may be a simple way to do what was asked: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=srares13.kcs

Comment: [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: Previously in my answer, I merely posted a link to my extension. I was thinking that the extension's page is self explanatory in providing both the answer and how it works, but I should have also described my answer, appropriately, in words.

In addition, I didn’t post my extension, as an answer, anywhere else where it wouldn’t constitute a viable answer or solve the problem the OP has. With these being said, my answer may have been considered a spam, hence the downvote. Sorry for any inconvenience.

I edited the answer, and I hope I remediated the issue.

Comment: there's not really a need for an extension here anyway. VS Code has functionality built in for what this question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 38 x64 workstation

vs code 1.78.2

First, you select the target part of the first line.

Second, Then `Alt` + `Shift` + `Down Arrow`. You will select the corresponding part of the next line. If you want more, don't release `Alt` + `Shift`, just press the `Down Arrow` again and again and again.