# Column selection like Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible selecting multi-line columns like Visual Studio (or Notepad++ or other text editor)?

If I press <kbd>shift+Alt</kbd> buttons and move the <kbd>arrows</kbd> button the behavior of Visual Studio code is different from the other text editor.

Thanks!

Comment: Does Ctrl-Shift-Alt-Down Arrow do what you want?

Comment: Yes it works but I must press esc button to exit from the multi columns editor.  If you continue to write something it happens that all the rows previously selected are not deselcted. And this is the problem. I want to modify some rows up to the press of arrows key.

Answer (score 1):

v1.43 brought what you are looking for in a new "**Column Selection Mode**". Demo:

[image: column selection mode demo]

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91249:

> While this is checked, selecting with the mouse will create a column
>   selection and Shift+arrow keys and Shift+Page Up/Down keys will also
>   create column selection.

---

Also  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91361 which would act as **a toggle for preexisting selections** when enabling/disabling `Column Selection Mode`.  So a current selection would be modified to a column selection (including multiple cursors) when enabling the mode and vice-versa.

And https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91362 where enabling the `Column Selection Mode` would be **indicated in the Status Bar**.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_43#_column-selection-mode

> You can also disable Column Selection mode from the Status bar.